# Understanding of this contract with no "funds transfer"

Tags: etherscan, payments

I am learning the functionality of the following contract:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xb9955b00fb89456b1a0364cd392e81cd37f6bce8#code

To my surprise, while there are some "transfer" statements which encodes some "notification" regarding an upcoming payment; however, I just cannot find the real `call/send/transfer` statements that perform the external contract call.

Am I missed anything there? I just cannot imagine a function can have no contract external calls. Any comments or explanations would be strongly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear IMO. What do you mean "I just cannot find the real call/send/transfer statements that perform the external contract call"??? If it's external, then why do you expect to find it in the contract?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "a function can have no contract external calls"??? Of course a function can have no external calls!

Comment: @goodvibration  by saying "external contract calls", I mean a `call`, a `'transfer`', or a `'send` which talks with "external" contracts on the blockchain.

Comment: This contract looks like a standard (probably ERC20) token. There doesn't need to be any `transfer` or `send` involved here, unless you want to bind this token to Ether payment (and even then, you could do that via the fallback function, without any `transfer` or `send`).

Comment: Also, it looks like it is designated to implement a certain set of functions (specifically the ERC20 functions I believe). You can inherit this contract, and then add whatever you want to add for the purpose of Ether trade. In fact, it is most likely the purpose of this contract (for others to inherit from it), so the `transfer`/`send` part is left for anyone who wishes to add it.

Comment: @goodvibration I see. Thank you very much. Thank makes a lot of sense to me.